# Getting/Setting Camera LED Status Light iusing videoinput/Logitech c930e

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I am using OpenCV 3.1 with Windows 10 and VS2012 C++/CLI.
In addition, I am using the videoinput library as the camera interface and that uses DirectShow.

Currently, I can access the camera settings using the CameraControl Properties (e.g., focus) as follows:

```
typedef enum  {
    CameraControl_Pan,
    CameraControl_Tilt,
    CameraControl_Roll,
    CameraControl_Zoom,
    CameraControl_Exposure,
    CameraControl_Iris,
    CameraControl_Focus
} CameraControlProperty;

typedef enum   {
    CameraControl_Flags_Auto     = 0x0001,
    CameraControl_Flags_Manual   = 0x0002
} CameraControlFlags;

void Channel::FocusControl(bool tAutoFocusOn)
{
    long mDefaultmin,mDefaultmax,mDefaultStep,mDefaultFlags,mDefaultValue,mDefaultfocus;

    try
    {
       CameraVI->getVideoSettingCamera(CameraNumber,CameraControl_Focus,mDefaultmin,mDefaultmax,mDefaultStep,mDefaultfocus,mDefaultFlags,mDefaultValue);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("Camera unable to set focus!","Camera Error Focus",MessageBoxButtons::OK,MessageBoxIcon::Error);
    return;
    }

    if(tAutoFocusOn)
       CameraVI->setVideoSettingCamera(CameraNumber,CameraControl_Focus,mDefaultfocus,CameraControl_Flags_Auto);
    else
        CameraVI->setVideoSettingCamera(CameraNumber,CameraControl_Focus,mDefaultfocus,CameraControl_Flags_Manual);
}
```

Where CameraVI is a pointer the the camera instance.

The Logitech cameras have an LED light which indicates that they are on and I want to turn that off.  That does not seem to be part of the CameraControl properties.

However, I do see the KSPROPERTY and KSCAMERA_EXTENDEDPROP classes/structures.  Which, if any of these controls the LED light (TORCH_MODE?) and how do I access it?  I am new to all of this so any code examples would be great.

Thanks,
James

Comment: you want to turn off the camera, or just the LED (while camera is still running)?

Comment: Just the LED while the camera is still running.